# R for loop implementation

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, iteration

I am new to coding so please dont be too hard with me:

I have the following code
-> i have and output column `expndr_output_bycountry` and I wanted to assign each value of this to a variable `phi_1990 - phi_2000`

is there anyone who could help me out building a loop around this?

```
phi_1990 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1990)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1991 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1991)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1992 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1992)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1993 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1993)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1994 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1994)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1995 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1995)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1996 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1996)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1997 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1997)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1998 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1998)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_1999 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==1999)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2000 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2000)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2001 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2001)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2002 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2002)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2003 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2003)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2004 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2004)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2005 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2005)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2006 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2006)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2007 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2007)%>%
  select(phi)
phi_2008 <- expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2008)%>%
  select(phi)
```

I tried this but its not working

```
for (i in expndr_output_bycountry)
{

expndr_output_bycountry %>%
  filter(year==2008)%>%
  select(phi)
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: There's a conceptual error in your `for` condition: when you say `i in expndr_output_bycountry`, R interprets `i` as each _element_ in `expndr_output_bycountry`. Since `expndr_output_bycountry` is presumably a `data.frame` — that is, a list of vectors that serve as columns — then your `for` loop treats `i` as a _column_. Furthermore, you never use `i` anyway. If I had to infer your intended looping logic, I would suggest `for(i in expndr_output_bycountry$year {expndr_output_bycountry %>% filter(year==2008)%>% select(phi)}`. However, this will still only _print_ the data, rather than store it.

Comment: This is a fairly frequent question, and the answer is always: don’t create separate variables in the first place. Use a list instead. Once you’ve changed this, implementing a loop (or, better, a list application) is straightforward.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what your ultimate objective is here - what you are doing is very inefficient, and if there's a desired final output you can share, we can provide alternative code to get you there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Something like `phi_by_year <- split(expndr_output_bycountry %>% select(phi), expndr_output_bycountry$year); names(phi_by_year) <- paste("phi", names(phi_by_year), sep = "_")`?  Or alternatively `dplyr::group_split()`?

Comment: @Greg There are many ways to skin a cat, yes. I like your answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just checked out your `box` package, and I'm loving the concept!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `expndr_output_bycountry` is a `data.frame`, containing (at least) the columns `year` and `phi`, here's a `base` approach (beyond your existing `dplyr` usage) that will consolidate all those variables within one convenient `list`:

```
library(dplyr)

# ...
# Code to generate the 'expndr_output_bycountry' dataset.
# ...

# Target only those years you're interested in.
years_of_interest <- 1990:2000

# Split up the selected columns (here 'phi') by corresponding year, and store each
# segment as a separate list entry, named by year.
phi_by_year <- split(x = expndr_output_bycountry %>% select(phi),
                     # Ensure all years of interest are covered, rather than only those
                     # mentioned in the 'year' column.
                     f = factor(x = expndr_output_bycountry$year,
                                levels = years_of_interest),
                     # Represent years with no data as empty tables (FALSE), or leave
                     # them out altogether (TRUE).
                     drop = FALSE)

# Rename each element in the list as `phi_YYYY' rather than 'YYYY'.
names(phi_by_year) <- paste("phi", names(phi_by_year), sep = "_")
```

From the `phi_by_year` list, you can now access each variable like so:

```
phi_by_year$phi_1990

phi_by_year$phi_1991

# ...

phi_by_year$phi_2000
```

If you ever want to split up `expndr_output_bycountry` by a *combination* of variables, rather than by `year` alone, you should look into [`dplyr::group_split()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html).

**Be warned!** Since `group_split()` does not name the list elements on its own, you will probably need [`dplyr::group_keys()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_data.html) to match each element in the list with the grouping values (like `year`) that define it, and so to rename each element according to one of those values (as we did with `year`).